# when can you say a complete graph has an L-coloring?

Tags: graph-theory

i think in general, for an arbitrary graph to have an L-coloring is NP-completeness. but when can you say a complete graph has an L-coloring?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by $L$-colouring you are referring to the List Colouring problem, where each vertex $v$ of the input graph $G$ is assigned a list $L(v)$ of colours, and we have to decide if there's a proper colouring $c$ of $V(G)$ where $c(v) \in L(v)$ for each $v$. There are two interesting answers to your question:

> What is the smallest bound $b$ such that we can guarantee that $G$ is $L$-colourable if $|L(v)| \geq b$ for all $v$?

This is known the Choosability problem. For complete graphs it is easy to see that if all lists are of length at least $n$, then the graph is colourable. Conversely it should also be obvious that if we only guarantee that the lists are of length at least $n-1$, then we could have the same list for every vertex, and the graph would not be colourable. Hence the choosability of $K_{n}$ is $n$ (indeed, for any graph in general the choosability is at least the chromatic number, but may be unbounded).

Of course the choosability of a graph doesn't preclude some particular cases with smaller lists being colourable, it's just the minimum needed to guarantee colourability no matter what the lists are.

> Given a complete graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, a set of colours $C$ and a list function $L:V(G) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(C)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(C)$ is the power set of $C$), is $G$ colourable with $L$?

As you note, for general graphs this problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. For complete graphs however, we can solve this in polynomial time. As each vertex in the graph is adjacent to every other vertex, each vertex must be assigned a unique colour. So what we can do is create a bipartite graph where one side is $V(G)$, and the other is $C$ and there is an edge between vertex $v \in V(G)$ and colour $c\in C$ if $c \in L(v)$. We then run a maximum matching algorithm on this auxiliary graph. If all the vertices in $V(G)$ are matched, then we answer YES, otherwise we answer NO.

Hopefully it's clear that the matching gives a colouring of $G$ - each vertex gets assigned some colour, and no two vertices can have been matched to the same colour. For the other direction, suppose we have some colouring, then we can use this to get a maximum matching, by matching each vertex with the colour it is assigned. A key thing to note is that because $G$ is complete, no two vertices can be assigned the same colour, so we can't have the case where we're trying to match two vertices to the same colour. It is a *maximum* matching because every vertex is assigned some colour, and as the auxiliary graph is bipartite, the size of a maximum matching can't be bigger than the smaller of the two sets of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $L$-colouring only means that it is colourable with $L$ colours (if not, please correct me): the chromatic number of the complete graph on $n$ vertices, $K_n$, is $n$. So it will have an $L$-colouring if and only if $L \ge n$.